# MSSQL - Convert from money to datetime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks to some wonderful application design, I've come to find myself face-to-face with a real WTF - it seems that the application I support outputs the date and time into two separate columns in one particular table; the date goes into a 'Date' column as the `datetime` data type, whilst the time goes into a 'Time' column as the `money` data type in minutes and seconds (so, for example, 10:35:00 would be £10.35).

I need to amalgamate these two columns during a query I'm making to the database so it returns as one complete `datetime` column but obviously just doing...

```
...snip...
CAST(au.[Date] as datetime) + CAST(au.[Time] AS datetime) as 'LastUpdateDate'
...snip...
```

... doesn't work as I hoped (naivély) that it would.

My predecessor encountered this issue and came up with a... "creative" solution to this:

```
MIN(DATEADD(HOUR,CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[time],0),CHARINDEX('.',CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[time],0),0)-1) AS INT),DATEADD(MINUTE,CAST(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[time],0),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[time],0)) - CHARINDEX('.',CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[time],0),0)) AS INT),[date]))) AS CreatedDateTime
```

Unlike my predecessor, I would rather try to keep this solution as simple as possible. Do you think it would be possible to cast the values in this column to time by:

1. Casting the money value to string
2. Replacing the decimal point for a colon
3. Parsing this as a datetime object (to replace the `CAST(au.[Time] as datetime)` part of the first code block

Is this feasible? And if not, can anyone assist?

#### EDIT

Just to be 100% clear, I *cannot* change the underlying data type for the column as the application relies on the data type being `money`. This is purely so my sanely-written application that does housekeeping reports can actually read the data in as a complete `datetime` value.

Comment: Your question makes no sense without examples of what the data looks like.  Storing date/time values as `money` is definitely non-standard.

Comment: What's the unit of the time? `money` is just a numeric data type, so you convert it to a `decimal` of the desired precision and then `dateadd` -- but you do need to know if you're adding seconds, milliseconds or something else entirely.

Comment: Oh wait, are they storing, say, `13:56` as `13.56`? That'd be hilarious. `FLOOR($13.56) * 60 + 100 * ($13.56 - FLOOR($13.56))` is that value in minutes.

Comment: Hi both! To clarify, the time is stored as MM.ss

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's correct, and believe me it is NOT hilarious to work with (though the "time is money" puns have been banded about between myself and my DBA colleagues...)

Comment: Your question now says "minutes and seconds", but your actual example is hours and minutes (which does make more sense). Can you confirm there are actually no seconds?

Comment: That was a good design :) , its good that  you are working on it to sort it out. I have tried this in a similar situation `select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)+ cast( cast( replace('10.35','.',':')  as time) as datetime)`

Comment: @JeroenMostert my apologies, it was in fact hh.MM as you have rightly pointed out :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer an arithmetical convertation without any string castings

```
MIN(
    DATEADD(
        MINUTE, 
        FLOOR(au.[Time]) * 60 + (au.[Time]-FLOOR(au.[Time])) * 100, 
        au.[Date])
) AS CreatedDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a layer of sanity, if changing the column to `time` outright is not an option:

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD SaneDate AS 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR([Time]) * 60 + 100 * ([Time] - FLOOR([Time])), [Date])
```

One computed column and then you can stick to using that instead of repeating the calculations everywhere. If altering the tables in any way is out of the question, you could at least make a view or table-valued function to capture this logic. (Preferably not a scalar function, although that's more obvious -- those have horrendous performance in queries.)

---

I tend to prefer `DATEADD` over string manipulation when possible, simply because the results tend to be more predictable. In this case there's no real issue, since converting `money` to `char(5)` is perfectly predictable regardless of language settings, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at how to use the `REPLACE` command and it works as expected:

```
CAST(au.[Date] as datetime) + CAST(REPLACE(CAST(au.[Time] AS varchar(5)),'.',':') AS datetime) as 'LastUpdateDate'
```

now outputs `2018-01-10 10:32:00.000` whereas before it was providing some incorrect date and time value.

I suppose you could mathematically convert it as @JeroenMostert has suggested - to be fair I'm not 100% on the performance impact this solution may have against calculating the minutes and converting it that way so I'll give that a try as well just to be sure.

Comment: You will need to run to check performance impact on million rows, as i believe your database must be huge depending on traditional application design. It is always good to correct the datatype at least now, rather later

Comment: It's an audit log so I believe there are about 15 million rows! And unfortunately I can't change the underlying data types of the column as the application depends on these data types (stupidly); I'm just trying to extract meaningful data from the rows!

Comment: It could be a better idea to create another staging table that populates data from this table to another for reporting purpose